Expo/EAS - Upload dSYM automatically to Firebase Crashlytics
What is the correct way to automatically upload the dSYM to Crashlytics using managed EAS flow?
I have already added the corresponding "buildArtifactPaths": ["ios/build/*"] to the eas.json so I can get the artifact and upload it manually, but I am not sure where and how to execute the suggested /path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs command for the automatic upload

EAS Build looks at package.json for some lifecycle hooks. Seems like eas-build-on-success is the one we're looking for.
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/npm-hooks/
It would be great if we could get this figured out and added to the RNFB Crashlytics documentation page! I'm still stuck on figuring out the exact command to put in this hook script!
